# If $p(x)$ is an odd polynomial, prove that $p(x)=x \cdot q(x)$ where $q(x)$ is an even polynomial

Tags: functions

> > Question: A function $f(x)$ is called even if $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x$, and odd if $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$.
> >
> > If $p(x)$ is an odd polynomial, prove that $p(x)=x \cdot q(x)$ where $q(x)$ is an even polynomial

---

so basically what side of the proof do I have to start from? I was thinking the right hand side

I am having trouble understanding how to 'prove' this...

Comment: First prove that $p$ has no constant term.  Then you can factor out an $x$.  Then you just have to prove the remainder $q$ is even...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $p$ be an odd polynomial. Since $p(0)=p(-0)=-p(0)$, it is clear that $p$ has no constant term.  So we can factor out an $x$; $$p(x)=x\cdot q(x).$$

Now $$q(-x)=\frac{p(-x)}{-x}=\frac{-p(x)}{-x}=\frac{p(x)}{x}=q(x).$$

Answer (score 1):

If $p(0) = a$,
then
$p(x) = xq(x)+a$,
where $q(x)$
is $p(x)$
with the constant term removed.

If $p$ is odd,
then
$p(x) = -p(-x)$,
so
$xq(x)+a
=-(-xq(-x)+a)
$
or
$xq(x)+a
=xq(-x)-a
$.

Putting $x=0$,
this gives
$a = -a$
so that
$a=0$.

Therefore
$xq(x)
=xq(-x)
$,
so that
$q(x) = q(-x)$
so that
$q$ is exen.